# Convert Google KMS signatures from DER-encoded format to .Net IEEE 1363 format

Tags: c#, cryptography, public-key-encryption, der, google-cloud-kms

I would like to convert signature in DER-encoded format (which I get from google KMS service) to IEEE 1363 format using C# (in order to validate the signature)
How it is done in C#, .Net Core 5 ?

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 5, both the ASN.1/DER and the IEEE P1363 formats are supported for ECDSA signatures, see e.g. [`SignData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.signdata?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-ecdsa-signdata(system-byte()-system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname-system-security-cryptography-dsasignatureformat)) and [`VerifyData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.verifydata?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-ecdsa-verifydata(system-byte()-system-byte()-system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname-system-security-cryptography-dsasignatureformat)) (similarly  [`SignHash()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.signhash?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-ecdsa-signhash(system-byte()-system-security-cryptography-dsasignatureformat)) and [`VerifyHash()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa.verifyhash?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-ecdsa-verifyhash(system-byte()-system-byte()-system-security-cryptography-dsasignatureformat))).

A specification of the format is possible with [`DSASignatureFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.dsasignatureformat?view=net-6.0) with the values `IeeeP1363FixedFieldConcatenation` (IEEE P1363) and `Rfc3279DerSequence` (ASN.1/DER). Default is IEEE P1363.

For other versions C#/BouncyCastle can be applied.

If you want to convert the signatures *directly*, the easiest way is to use an ASN.1 parser (e.g. from C#/BouncyCastle).